# Running a Laravel Artisan command detached via nohup

Tags: php, laravel, process, nohup

I have to trigger a Laravel Artisan command from PHP so it runs as a detached process in the background, and trying to use **nohup** to achieve this:

```
$base_path = base_path();
shell_exec("nohup /usr/local/bin/php {$base_path}/artisan tms:parse --alias=some_alias --keep > nohup.out & > /dev/null");
```

**shell_exec** is always returning **null**, so not getting a PID as expected.

Any ideas what's wrong?

When I change to

```
shell_exec("nohup /usr/local/bin/php {$base_path}/artisan tms:parse --alias=some_alias --keep > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
```

I get a PID, but running **ps** or **top** it's clear the script exited earlier than expected. Runnin the nohup command directly in the command line works fine, so it only fails when trying to run it from within a PHP script.